# How do I return an unsaved variable in a PHP form?

Tags: php, forms, drupal-7

SOLVED: Thanks to @riggsfolly for pointing me in the right direction. I should have looked at Drupal Forms API to begin with.  Added an form element of type 'item' and it worked like a charm:

```
$form['description'] = array('#type'=> 'item', '#title'=> t('To maintain consistency across your course, use the link below to select whether you plan to grade assessments based on points or percentages.'),);
```

UPDATE: I should have mentioned this is a Drupal form. Sorry.

[PHP Newbie] I am working with the following code I didn't write:

```
function grading_method_form($form, &$form_state){
    $courseId = $_SESSION['courseId'];
    $gradingMethodDetails = getCourseGradingMethod($courseId);
    $form = array();
    $form['cid'] = array('#title'=>NULL,'#type'=>'hidden','#required'=>TRUE,'#value'=>$courseId,);
    $form['grading_method'] = array('#title'=>'','#type'=>'select','#default_value'=>$gradingMethodDetails['grading_method'],'#options'=>array(0=>'Percentage',1=>'Points'),);
    $form['submit'] = array('#type'=>'submit','#value'=>t('Save Grading Method'));
    return $form;
}
```

What I would like to include in this very simple form is a description for users about what they are doing here. I've tried adding this:

```
$form .= "To maintain consistency across your course, use the link below to select whether you plan to grade assessments based on points or percentages.";
```

as well as tried to move the whole form into another approach I've see elsewhere where I concatenate additional lines into the form using `$form .= 'My description info.';` to no avail.

All I want to do is to include a statement in the form before the select that informs the user what this is for.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I need more coffee today, but I don't get your question :/

Comment: `$form` is an array `.=` is string concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$form` is an array all you need to do is add another occurance to the array like

```
function grading_method_form($form, &$form_state){
    $courseId = $_SESSION['courseId'];
    $gradingMethodDetails = getCourseGradingMethod($courseId);
    $form = array();
    $form['cid'] = array('#title'=>NULL,'#type'=>'hidden','#required'=>TRUE,'#value'=>$courseId,);
    $form['grading_method'] = array('#title'=>'','#type'=>'select','#default_value'=>$gradingMethodDetails['grading_method'],'#options'=>array(0=>'Percentage',1=>'Points'),);
    $form['submit'] = array('#type'=>'submit','#value'=>t('Save Grading Method'));


    $form['new_message'] = "To maintain consistency across your course, use the link below to select whether you plan to grade assessments based on points or percentages.";

    return $form;
}
```

Of course you will then have to look at the code that deals with the result of this function and do something appropriate with this new occurance.

Comment: just beat me too it :(

Comment: @RiggsFolly - perfect - that was something else I tried. But the function that uses the form data obviously doesn't do anything with the new occurrence. Does it need to? If the other occurrences are used but this one just sits in the array unchecked and unused, is it a problem?

Comment: Unused is not a problem. But Like i said in the final sentence. You will now have to chnage the code that shows the page to make it use this new message

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly. You are trying to add another value to the $form array.

Because it is an array you cannot append a string to it like $form .= 'text';

You could if is was just a variable, for example:

```
$form = 'hello';
$form .= ' this is a form';
echo $form;
```

This would display 'hello this is a form'

But because your $form is an array you would have to add the string on liek this:

```
$form['string'] = 'your string';
```

which would like something like:

```
array(

    ['string'] => 'your string'

)
```

And with the rest of $form it would look something like:

```
Array
(
[cid] => Array
    (
        [#title] => 
        [#type] => hidden
        [#required] => 1
        [#value] => 1
    )

[grading_method] => Array
    (
        [#title] => 
        [#type] => select
        [#default_value] => 1
        [#options] => Array
            (
                [0] => Percentage
                [1] => Points
            )

    )

[submit] => Array
    (
        [#type] => submit
        [#value] => 1
    )
[string] => 'your text string here'

)
```

Comment: Thanks virepo - I just don't know what to do with that extra occurrence.

Comment: Well it depends what you need it doing